# Concurrent Stored Procedure calls are causing delay while retuning data

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, optimization

While calling multiple Stored procedures from the .net framework API asynchronously, it is taking long time for the sql server to return data. But while calling the same stored procedures individually or one by one from API, sql server is returning data significantly faster.

To optimize the performance I have already enabled SET NOCOUNT ON, tried local variable to avoid parameter sniffing and also tried SET ARITHABORT ON, but eventually having the same outcome.
I am using angularjs in frontend, .net framework for the api.

[image]

In the above screenshot, the Last Elapsed Time is shown in micro seconds, and each row is representing different stored procedure.

NOTE:

•   There are 4 different SPs, which are not dependent on each other.

•   All these SPs are doing read operations only, no write or update operation.

While calling the SPs asynchronously, they should be executed and return corresponding data independently. but that is not happening. When I am calling 1 sp it takes 3-4 second, while calling 2 it becomes 8 second, while calling 4, then it becomes 16-18 second for the overall process, even though the calls are asynchronous

I  have provided 2 SPs along with API and repo

API code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDataAPI(string param1, string param2, string param3, string param4, string param5, bool? Param6, bool? Param7, string param8, string param9, bool? param10, bool? param11, string param12, int? param13)
{
    Model model = await _repo.GetData(param1, param2, param3, param4, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8, param9, param10, param11);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, overview);
}
```

Repo code:

```
public async Task<model> GetData(string param1, string param2, string param3, string param4, string param5, bool? Param6, bool? Param7, string param8, string param9, bool? param10, bool? param11, string param12, int? param13)
{
    var _param1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1) ? new SqlParameter("@param1", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@param1", param1);
    var _param2 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2) ? new SqlParameter("@param2", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@param2", param2);
    var _param3 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(param3) ? new SqlParameter("@param3", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@param3", param3);
    var _param4 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(param4) ? new SqlParameter("@param4", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@param4", param4);
    var _param5 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(param5) ? new SqlParameter("@param5", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@param5", param5);
    var _param6 = !param6.HasValue ? new SqlParameter("@param6", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@param6", param6);
    var _param7 = !param7.HasValue ? new SqlParameter("@param7", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@param7", param7);
    var _param8 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(param8) ? new SqlParameter("@param8", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@param8", param8);
    var _param9 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(param9) ? new SqlParameter("@param9", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@param9", param9);
    var _param10 = !param10.HasValue ? new SqlParameter("@param10", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@param10", param10);
    var _param11 = !param11.HasValue ? new SqlParameter("@param11", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@param11", param11);

    return await _databaseContext.Database.SqlQuery<model>("exec sp1 @param1, @ param2, @ param3, @ param4, @ param5, @ param6, @ param7, @ param8,@ param9,@ param10,@ param11", _param1, _param2, _param3, _param4, _param5, _param6, _param7, _param8, _param9, _param10, _param11).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Here is one of the SPs:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1]            
@param1 bit=NULL,                                               
@param2 nvarchar(100)=NULL,                                               
@param3 bit=NULL,                                                  
@param4 nvarchar(100)=NULL,                                
@param5 bit = Null,                                            
@param6 nvarchar(100)=NULL,                         
@param7 nvarchar(50) = Null,                          
@param8 nvarchar(100) = Null,                          
@param9 bit = Null,                
@param10 nvarchar(30) = Null,                
@param11 int = Null                  
                  
AS                                      
BEGIN                                      
 SET NOCOUNT ON;          
 --Set arithabort on;    
                   
      declare @parameter1 int , @parameter2 int, @parameter3 int                      
                      
                        
   select @parameter1 = count(distinct a.col1)                            
   from table1 a                                     
                                 
    where        
 ((col2) in (SELECT * FROM string_split((@param4), ',')))         
 and (@param1 is null or @param1= a.col12)                                          
    and (@param3 is null or  @param3=a.col16)                                      
    and (@param6 is null or @param6=a.col18)                                          
    and (@param2 is null or @param2=a.col17)                                          
    and (@param5 is null or @param5=a.col3)                                      
        AND (@param7 is null or @param7 = a.col7)                          
    AND (@param8 is null or @param8 = a.col19)                          
                             
    AND (@param9 is null or @param9 = a.col21)                          
    and (@param10 is null or @param10 = a.col25)                
 and (@param11 is null or @param11 = a.col26)                 
                           
    select                         
   @parameter2 = ISNULL(SUM(a.col13),0),                             
   @parameter3 = ISNULL(SUM(a.col8),0)                               
    from table2 a                                                
   where ((col2) in (SELECT * FROM string_split((@param4), ','))) and                
   (@param2 is null or @param2 = a.col12) and                  
   (@param6 is NULL or @param6=a.col9) AND                               
  (@param7 is null or @param7=a.col16) and                              
   (@param8 is null or @param8=a.col11)  and                            
   (@param1 is null or @param1 = a.col3) and                            
   (@param5 is null or @param5 = a.col6)  and    
   (@param3 is null or @param3 = a.col4) and                  
   (@param9 is null or @param9 = a.col5)                  
    and (@param10 is null or @taxId = a.col14)                
 and (@param11 is null or @grouper = a.col17)                 
                         
  SELECT @parameter1 AS column1, @parameter2 AS column2, @parameter3 as column3                      
                                      
END
```

Here is another SP for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_List_code
@nh nvarchar(100)=NULL,
@ctr nvarchar(100)=NULL,
@as nvarchar(100)=NULL,
@st nvarchar(100)=NULL,
@cnt nvarchar(100)=NULL,
@sc nvarchar(100)=NULL,
@ncm bit = Null,
@rc nvarchar(100)=NULL,
@io bit = null,
@ti nvarchar(30) = Null,
@gr int = Null,
@pn bigint=1,
@ps bigint=20AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ats int;
DECLARE @oc bit;
DECLARE @pgn int;
DECLARE @pgs int;
DECLARE @shc nvarchar(50);
Declare @t nvarchar(30);
Declare @gi int;
SET @ats = @as;
SET @oc = @io;
set @pgn=@pn;
set @pgs=@ps;
SET @shc=@sc;
SET @t=@ti ;
SET @gi=@gr; SET NOCOUNT ON; select  mi,mci,fn,ln,st,cnt,gd,ma1,zc,nth,ctr,phn
   ,cc,ats,CAST(tg as nvarchar(100)) as tg,
   CAST(cg as nvarchar(100)) as cg, rn,
   cast((A.tg-A.cg) as nvarchar(100)) as og   from(
  select distinct a.mi,mci,fn,ln,st,cnt,gd,ma1,zc,nth,ctr,phn
   ,cc,ats,a.tg, a.cg,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by a.mi) as rn
   from a
   where a.hsc in (SELECT * FROM string_split(@shc, ','))
        and (@st is null or @st=a.st)
   and (@nh is null or @nh= a.nth)
    and (@ctr is null or @ctr=a.ctr)
  and (@ats is null or  @ats=a.ats)
  and (@rc is null or @rc=a.rc)  and (@cnt is null or @ccnt=a.cnt)
  and (@ncm is null or @ncm=a.ncm)
  and (@oc is null or @oc=a.hog)
  and (@t is null or @t = a.ti)
  and (@gi is null or @gi = a.gi)
    )A    where A.rn > (@pgn-1)*@pgs and A.rn <= @pgn*@pgs
END
```

Comment: Those are very "nice" kitchen sink procedures. And by nice I mean not nice, of course. For starters they're so generic that `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` would not go amiss. Pagination is also very hard to do efficiently in general, even with an optimal plan. See [here](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for much more background information.

Comment: Most likely these queries perform extremely poor. Your queries are a horror for most databases and may lead to cases where they can't effectively use indexes and require multiple full table scans. Start with looking at the exeution plan of your query and get it to perform properly. And naming columns, parameters and variables like this is really poor coding practice, makes it error prone and impossible to understand what it is attempting to do

Comment: Well, these variable names and column names are basically dummy names, for certain reasons I am not allowed to share production code here, sorry.

Comment: I suggest query/index tuning plus the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` @JeroenMostert suggested. As to why queries run longer when run concurrently, it's probably resource constraints (e.g.. CPU) on the database server. Tuning will help fix that.

Comment: I would also second `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`, although if there are certain combinations which are heavily used you may want to specifically code for them also. Look into [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), it is far more efficient. Prune the queries for any unnecessary columns. Ensure indexes are hit wherever possible. `DISTINCT` indicates the joins were not thought through. Dump the `string_split` into a temp table or table variable first.

Comment: @DanGuzman After adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) there haven't been much improvements in terms of performance except it is taking 1 or 2 second lesser than previously. 
On the other suggestion, we are working on the tuning, so further suggestion regarding that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Charlieface After adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) there haven't been much improvements in terms of performance except it is taking 1 or 2 second lesser than previously. On the other suggestion, we are working on the tuning, so further suggestion regarding that will be highly appreciated.